# How to use RNCryptor and Firebase togeather - Swift & Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, rncryptor

is it possible to use RNCryptor and firebase together? You cant store NSData into firebase and thats what RNCryptor uses?

What other ways can i encrypt users data for the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes! you can use it with Firebase.

We have RNCryptor integrated into a project and are using it to encrypt and decrypt private data stored in Firebase.

Encrypt in ObjC

```
NSString *plainText = @"Hello!"
NSData *data = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:aKey
                                           error:&error];

NSString *stringFromEncryptedData = [encryptedData 
         base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Here's a decrypt pattern in ObjC

```
NSData *dataFromEncryptedString = [[NSData alloc] 
          initWithBase64EncodedString:encryptedString 
                              options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
NSError *error;
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:dataFromEncryptedString
                                    withPassword:aKey
                                           error:&error];

NSString *plainText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Note that aKey is the secret string pattern you want to use to encrypt/decrypt your plain text string.

Comment: legend! Works great it saves into firebase perfectly as a random jumble of characters

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Encrypt Function in swift

```
func EncryptData(text: String) -> String {
    let Data: NSData = String(text).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let Password = "Secret password"
    let EncryptedText = RNCryptor.encryptData(Data, password: "Secret password")

    return EncryptedText.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
}
```

and here is my Decrypt Function

```
func DecryptData(text: String) -> String {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: text, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
    do {
        let originalData = try RNCryptor.decryptData(decodedData!, password: MasterKey)
        return  String(data: originalData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    } catch {
        return "Data Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Nice and clean.